# Explain pushing into array

Tags: javascript

I was trying to learn some JS from this [HTML5 canvas snake game guide](http://www.competa.com/blog/how-to-build-a-snake-game-using-javascript-and-html5-canvas/).

But I’m stuck at the part with the `push`:

```
for (var i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
  snake.push({ x: i, y: 0 });
}
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Is the documentation on sites like MDN not enough?

Comment: [Arrays - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays)

Comment: It's almost like you didn't even try to look it up:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: Are you confused about the [object literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)?

Comment: I mean the part with the variables in the paranthesis

Comment: @RKJ Which one? `i`? `length`? `snake`?

Comment: So there are two things. There is the object initializer (the curly braces and what is in it). This is a short way of making an object with properies `x` which set to the value of `i` and `y` set to `0`. And there is the push method which appends something to an array. That something in this case is the object mentioned before. I guess this is initializing the snake in the top left corner, where it will occupy the squares `0` to `length`, where `length` is likely the initial length of the snake.

Answer (score 1):

push is a method which pushes the data at the end of the existing array without having to know the index of your array. so if your data is not for a specific index and can be at the end in stack, just use the push method. the output would be-

old val of  array1 : `['ab','bc', 'ca']`

`array1.push('cz');`

new value of  array1 : `['ab','bc', 'ca', 'cz']`